Chiral carbon of a ring
If a carbon of cyclopentane is attached to an ethyl and methyl group, will it be chiral or non-chiral?
How does chirality work, if the carbon atom considered is a part of a ring?

If one of the carbon atoms of the cyclopentane has a methyl and a ethyl group, it will still be achiral because it will superimpose on its mirror image. Clearly, the carbon atom in observation has two of the same "thing" attached to it.

Note subscriber user55119 provides again and again very instructive illustrated answers about the application of CIP rules in general, including work with cyclic structures/unfold them (example).

@Nightwing To be technical on this point, that depends heavily on the conformation of the ring. However, I believe the floppiness of this cyclopentyl ring will provide access to all conformations, even if the most likely ground state(s) were chiral.

In the numbered version of 1-ethyl-1-methylcyclopentane there exists a plane of symmetry that passes through the $\ce{C3-C4}$ bond and the plane of $\ce{C6-C1-C7-C8}$. This conformation is achiral. The conformation of these four atoms is reminiscent of the anti-conformation of n-butane with a dihedral angle of 180 degrees. When the $\ce{C6-C1-C7-C8}$ dihedral angle is 0 degrees, the conformation is also achiral. But both of these conformations are minor contributors to the myriad of pairs of  enantiomers that can exist. The slightest movement of an atom in either achiral conformation produces a chiral conformation that forms a racemate pair.
If rotation of the $\ce{C1-C7}$ bond occurs 120 degrees in the counterclockwise direction, conformation (P)-1 is formed with equal probability that rotation occurs in clockwise direction producing conformation (M)-1 (see the red box). But $\ce{C1}$ in this example is shown at the "flap" of the cyclopentane ring. In conformation 2 ($\ce{C6-C1-C7-C8}$ dihedral angle 0 degrees), $\ce{C1}$ is not the "flap" carbon; this conformation is chiral as is its enantiomer, (ent)-2. It is the racemic conformations that are the major contributors to the lack of optical activity, not the the achiral conformations.


This is a very solid answer. The choice of the envelope conformation may be the most reasonable, but it's possible that the heavy substitution on the 1-carbon might produce a twist, leading to two chiral conformations.

@Zhe: One could go on forever considering other options. This should be enough for the OP's needs.
